# Searching through a directory to return fixed file based on number

Tags: python, file

I have written a small function which takes as input a code number and searches through a directory for the appropriate file which contains the code number
code-

```
currentdir="E:\\ist\\text files"
def get_file(code):


    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(currentdir):
        for name in files:
            print(name,str(code)+"SummaryData.edf",str(code)+"SummaryData.TXT")
            if ((name==str(code)+"SummaryData.edf") or (name==str(code)+"SummaryData.TXT")):
                print(name,code)

                return(root,name)
```

the directory has files like-

```
405AllEvents.TXT 
406SummaryData.TXT 
407SummaryData.TXT 
408ScoredEvents.TXT 
408SummaryData.TXT 
409SummaryData.TXT 
410SummaryData.TXT
```

but the output I am getting(on printing what files it is searching through)
I get the names of all the files in the directory twice and then the function returns none.
So my question is what am I doing wrong?Is my code not able to parse through the directory and return the appropriate file?

Expected output should be(if the print statement is commented out) the required file for example if the code is 407 it should return `407SummaryData.TXT file name`

Comment: Can you post an example of the current output and expected output?

Comment: @malan the current output is the names of the all the files in the directory twice....it is big so I didnt add it

Comment: Using `""` for strings is not correct. Use `'` or `"`, preferably.

Answer (score 0):

The walk function is being called incorrectly.

This will not print anything because the directory `" "` is not found

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(" "):
    print(root, dirs, files)
```

If you want the current directory then use a `"."` for the directory

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    print(root, dirs, files)
```

The latter will recursively search from the current directory

Comment: I just didnt add the  current directory here coz its not relevant and would be different in others but I added it to avoid confusion